# Prepopulating excel header based on excel cell from different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to use Vba to populate the data from cell "H13" from **"DoNotPrint - Setup"** sheet and paste that text into the header of **"COVER"** sheet.

Note: I know you can do this with "&File" on excel but some people have extensions enabled so those carryover and add .xlsm extension at the end of the filename header which is not my intention.

The picture below shows a sample screenshot of how the **"COVER"** header is supposed to look like:
[image]

Below shows the screenshot of how the cell "H13" within **"DoNotPrint - Setup"** sheet
[image]

Code I have so far within the **"COVER"** sheet

```
Sub setheader()

    Dim Filename As String
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DoNotPrint - Setup")
    Filename = .Range("H13")
End With

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&B &12 PROPOSAL" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Filename & "&8"

End Sub
```

From the code above the font of the "Proposal" word is to be size 12, and header filename in size 8. But at the moment the font of the header filename is very big and doesn't conform to size 8 instead it became size 409. So I wonder what is wrong with my code?

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me (Win10, Excel 2016)

Comment: Maybe try `"&B &12 PROPOSAL" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & " &08 " & Filename`

Comment: @TimWilliams Yep, it worked thanks